# How to install Cucumber using Bundler in Windows 7

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cucumber

I have created a gem file similar to below, I'm trying this in windows 7 environment

```
source :rubygems

group :test do
gem 'cucumber', '1.2.1'
gem 'rspec-expectations', '2.11.2'
end
```

This is executed in cmd "C:\mysite\ruby test.rb"

```
System throw following error msg, 
test.rb:1:in '<main>' : undefined method 'source' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

I have changed the first line as

```
source 'http://rubygems.org/'
```

But still I getting same error. Really appreciate if anyone can give instructions, I'm very new to cucumber & ruby

Comment: @Sachin has already given the solution, but also avoid using spaces in filenames or you'll run into many problems.

Comment: **You are using an insecure source**! You should specify the HTTPS RubyGems source like so: `source 'https://rubygems.org'`.

Comment: I have changed the source as mentioned and still i'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First install bundler with

```
gem install bundler
```

Then go into your project directory. The gem file *must* be named `Gemfile`. Then you can just do

```
bundle install
```

Also, you should use HTTPS:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org/'
```

Comment: Thanks for quick respond. I have followed the instructions and 'gem install bundler' worked as expected but when I execute the bundle install command i got following error 'Bundler::GemfileNotFound'

Comment: Did you rename your file to `Gemfile`? Did you execute the command from the directory where `Gemfile` is?

Comment: Yes my file name is Gemfile.rb and the command executed from the directory where Gemfile is locate.

Comment: **Not** `Gemfile.rb`, just `Gemfile`.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you have put "source 'http://rubygems.org/' " line in
 'test.rb', which is not allowed, you must have the file Gemfile and
 put this code in Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org/

group :test do
  gem 'cucumber', '1.2.1'
  gem 'rspec-expectations', '2.11.2'
end
```

and do `bundle install`

Comment: Thanks for quick respond. I have followed the instructions and 'gem install bundler' worked as expected but when I execute the bundle install command i got following error 'Bundler::GemfileNotFound'

Comment: you should be at the root of your application, while doing 'bundle install'.